# Using WebStorage API with WordPress TinyMCE editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, tinymce

I want to keep the data what user wrote into the WordPress TinyMCE editor using the [WebStorage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API). I initiated the editor in front end in [one of my plugin](https://github.com/nanodesigns/nanosupport/blob/master/includes/shortcodes/ns-submit-ticket.php#L152-L166).

Condition is, after filling up the textarea user might choose whether to register or login, and at that state they need to refresh the page. I want to keep the typed texts into the [editor enabled] textarea even after the page refresh. I think webStorage would be the key.

But I can't trigger javascript (jQuery) into that TinyMCE editor enabled field. I can make it work while `'tinymce' => false`.

Is there any way I can save webStorage onKeyUp, either:

- injecting JavaScript to TinyMCE, or
- by any other method?

Comment: can you try to isolate WP's native TinyMCE instance, and load your custom lib from your plugin maybe?? and do whatever you like :) I had bad experiences with tinymce and what not,, I would suggest to save to webstorage on losing focus not keyup

Comment: Thanks, but I failed initiating TinyMCE in front end with all the possible code I found, except `wp_editor()`. If you have any active solution that can assist me triggering TinyMCE on any `<textarea>` in front end, then it'd be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

try to init TinyMCE with something like this,, I don't know if that will help you but I hold my fingers crossed for you..
also I have commented saving localstorage obj also there is some kind of limit that SO impose..

```js
// initialize tinymce:
// I loaded it over inline element (div) only cause StackOverflow editor
// can't init normal tinymce with iframe.. 
// you have to replace only this div with your custom textare and give it ID
// and reference it in code
// I have choosen to save text on blur but you can do whatever event you need to update localstorage object
tinymce.init({
  inline: true,
  selector: '#myid',
  height: 100,
  menubar: true,
});

$('#myid').on('blur', function(){
  var temp = $('#myid').text();
  console.log( temp );
  // localStorage.setItem('tempTxt',  temp  );
})
```

```css
#myid {
  height: 100px; width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.tinymce.com/4/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet prefetch" href="//www.tinymce.com/css/codepen.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" id="u0" href="http://cdn.tinymce.com/4/skins/lightgray/skin.min.css">

<div id=myid>My custom text ..</div>
```